# How to sort a table on multiple values in lua?

Tags: sorting, lua

I need a function
`sort_on_values(t, ...)`
where `...` are the variables by which the table `t` should be sorted.
or `sort_on_values(t, t_v)`
where `t_v` is a table with variables by which the table `t` should be sorted.
Or something like that.

Function returns sorted table or sorts existing one.

Example #1:

I have a table

```
t = {{a=1,b=2,c=3},
     {a=1,b=1,c=2},
     {a=3,b=2,c=2}}
```

I do this:

```
t = sort_on_values(t,a,b,c)
```

And as result I get:

```
t == {{a=1,b=1,c=2},
      {a=1,b=2,c=2},
      {a=3,b=2,c=2}}
```

Example #2:

I do this:

```
t = sort_on_values(t,b,a,c)
```

And as result I get:

```
t == {{a=1,b=1,c=2},
      {a=1,b=2,c=3},
      {a=3,b=2,c=2}}
```

This should also work if I have a table like

```
t = {{a=1,b=1,c=2,d=1},
     {a=1,b=2,c=3,d=2},
     {a=3,b=2,c=2,d=3}}
```

And so on.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variant for vararg function

```
function sort_on_values(t,...)
  local a = {...}
  table.sort(t, function (u,v)
    for i = 1, #a do
      if u[a[i]] > v[a[i]] then return false end
      if u[a[i]] < v[a[i]] then return true end
    end
  end)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Generic code for this task will probably take some work but you can start with this:

```
t = {
    {a=1,b=2,c=3},
    {a=1,b=1,c=2},
    {a=3,b=2,c=2},
}

function sort_on_values(t,a,b,c)
    table.sort(t, function (u,v)
        return
             u[a]<v[a] or
            (u[a]==v[a] and u[b]<v[b]) or
            (u[a]==v[a] and u[b]==v[b] and u[c]<v[c])
    end)
end

sort_on_values(t,"a","b","c")
for i=1,#t do
    print(i,t[i].a,t[i].b,t[i].c)
end
```

Comment: Wow cool thanks! Seems to work. But what if I have "d", "e" etc? 
Ideally, I would like to have a more general solution. 
It seems more difficult to implement.
But thanks anyway)